# CRM 2015 - Products tile not showing on Invoice entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

I am working with Microsoft CRM 2015, and if I go to Quote and expand the ribbon, I can see the Products tile, but on Invoice it does not appear. Does anybody know if I can add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the command bar (Save, New etc.) hit the "..." and select Form Editor.  At the top select "Navigation" and drag "Products" from the Relationship Explorer (right side) over to the menu (left side).  Save and then publish.